# Как нарисовать сглаженную кривую в Canvas по точкам?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть `Canvas`, в нем необходимо нарисовать непрерывную сглаженную кривую по точкам, `X` у каждой точки увеличивается на 1, `Y` меняется как угодно. Много есть подобного в интернете, но конкретный такой вопрос я не нашел. У меня в арсенале будет лишь список `List<Tuple<double,double>>` координат.

Comment: Вы бы хоть упомянули графическую библиотеку... Откуда мы тут знаем о каком именно Canvas речь?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел в итоге ответ в объекте `BezierSegment`
Вот примерный код :

```
PathFigure myPathFigure = new PathFigure();
        myPathFigure.StartPoint = new Point(10, 50);
        myPathFigure.Segments.Add(
            new BezierSegment(
                new Point(100, 0),
                new Point(200, 200),
                new Point(300, 100),
                true ));

        /// Create a PathGeometry to contain the figure.
        PathGeometry myPathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
        myPathGeometry.Figures.Add(myPathFigure);

        // Display the PathGeometry. 
        Path myPath = new Path();
        myPath.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
        myPath.StrokeThickness = 1;
        myPath.Data = myPathGeometry;

        Canvas.Children.Add(myPath);
```